# GridException Failed to add no-op logger for Log4j on GridGain startup

Tags: java, xml, caching, log4j, gridgain

I'm having trouble to get started with gridgain, i'm using the xml configuration file that come with gridgain examples [example-cache.xml](https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain/blob/master/examples/config/example-cache.xml) (Is there a simpler configuration file?).
When I start gridgain as follows I got a `GridException`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws GridException, URISyntaxException {
  URL url = GridgainCache.class.getClassLoader().getResource("gridgain.xml");
  String filename = url.toURI().toString();
  System.out.println("Reading gridgain conf from: "+filename);
  Grid g = GridGain.start(filename);
  ...
}
```

Here is full stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" class org.gridgain.grid.GridException: Failed to add no-op logger for Log4j.
For more information see:
    Troubleshooting:      http://bit.ly/GridGain-Troubleshooting
    Documentation Center: http://bit.ly/GridGain-Documentation

    at org.gridgain.grid.util.GridUtils.addLog4jNoOpLogger(GridUtils.java:7709)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx.start(GridGainEx.java:714)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx.start(GridGainEx.java:659)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx.start(GridGainEx.java:522)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx.start(GridGainEx.java:492)
    at org.gridgain.grid.GridGain.start(GridGain.java:314)
    at com.examples.gridgain.GridgainCache.main(GridgainCache.java:102)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gridgain.grid.util.GridUtils.addLog4jNoOpLogger(GridUtils.java:7706)
    ... 6 more
```

Do I need to configure log4j? i'm using slf4j.

Comment: It looks like you have log4j in your classpath (otherwise you would get ClassNotFoundException). What version of GridGain and what version of log4j are you using?

Comment: I've `log4j-1.2.12.jar` and `gridgain-core-6.5.0.jar`.

Comment: Just to make sure, do you have maven dependency on "gridgain-log4j" maven module? If yes, GridGain uses log4j-1.2.17. Can you switch to this version?

Comment: Mmm not sure if I can switch because it comes with something I depends on. I'm not using `gridgain-log4j`, do I have to add this dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GridGain checks if there are Log4j classes available in classpath and tries to add Log4j logger automatically, which in your case leads to the error because of Log4j version mismatch.

Since you cannot switch to the Log4j v1.2.17 supported by GridGain, you should configure another logger manually. I would use SLF4j bridge matching the version of Log4j you already have (note you will need to add gridgain-slf4j dependency):

```
<property name="gridLogger">
    <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.logger.slf4j.GridSlf4jLogger"/>
</property>
```

Another option is to use Java logging (no additional dependencies needed)

```
<property name="gridLogger">
    <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.logger.java.GridJavaLogger"/>
</property>
```